# Oracle APEX - dynamically generated region does not get refreshed

Tags: oracle-apex-5.1

I am trying to refresh dynamically generated region on a page from dynamic action. My dynamic region contains a select list loaded from the database. So from dynamic action I use Refresh Region. Not getting any errors but the values in my select do not get reloaded.

I would expect that as the region gets reloaded, the select list would reload as well

Comment: Have you possibly reviewed answers on your previous questions? I see you're an experienced user on this site, I believe you understand that reviewing the answers and tagging a correct/working solution is not only polite but needed for proper operation of this site.There are still some open questions, without tagged correct answer or at least a comment that explains why they do not work.

Comment: I am still in progress testing some of those solutions if you are referring to the last 3-4 questions

Comment: Yes, I've been referring to those questions.
Regarding this one, I'll need some info. Are you using classic report or some other type of region? And can you add to your question your used SQL query that populates that region?

Comment: That is a dynamic content region. It is populated by a PL/SQL procedure that generates a couple of select boxes using APEX_ITEM.SELECT_LIST

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the region needed to be refreshed if a certain value was set, I added a dynamic action for that item on change and just used APEX built-in Refresh and it worked

Comment: when I refer oracle docs, I see refresh for dynamic plsql content region  is not supported. Then how did it work?

Answer (score 0):

I think this (refresh the region with DA) is not possible for this type of region (PL/SQL dynamic content).

Why? I don't know...

---

Maybe you can transform all this PL/SQL in a function with the necessary parameters and use a classic report to show the result, in this case you can use the DA to refresh the content.

SELECT
myfunction(p1,p2,..,pn)
FROM
dual

Don't forget to set after this select in the field 'Itens to Submit' all the itens that you are using in this function.

In the attributes of this classic report you can change the html template, maybe there is one that you can use to show the content without header columns or borders...

if there isn't you can copy one classic report template and do the necessary change to render the region like you want.

Comment: I actually was able to refresh the region by setting Item's on change dynamic action and using Refresh action. Worked fine for me